# Constructing the projection of a projective module from its dual basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $M$ be a (left) module over a not necessarily commutative algebra $A$.
We can say that $M$ is *projective* if, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

i)  there exists a projection $P$ (i.e. $P \in M_n(A)$ and $P^2 = P$) such that 
$$
P(A^n) = M,
$$

OR EQUIVALENTLY

ii) if we have a **dual basis**, that is to say, a set $\{m_{i}\in M \mid i = 1, \dots,n\}$, and a set $\{f_{i} \in \mathrm {Hom}(M,A)\mid i = 1, \dots,n\}$ such that for every $x \in M$, 
$$
x = \sum_{i = 1}^n f_{i}(x)m_{i}.
$$

What I would like to know is: Given the dual basis, how can one construct the projection $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions given in the question are for *finitely generated* projective modules (although they can both be adapted for arbitrary projectives).

Given the dual basis, there are module homomorphisms $f:M\to A^n$ given by
$$f(x)=(f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)),$$
and $g:A^n\to M$ given by
$$g(a_1,\dots,a_n)=a_1m_1+\dots+a_nm_n.$$

The definition of a dual basis gives that $g\circ f=\text{id}_M$, so $f$ is a split monomorphism and $f\circ g:A^n\to A^n$ is an idempotent endomorphism of $A^n$ with image isomorphic to $M$.

So the projection you want is just $P=f\circ g$, or in other words
$$P(a_1,\dots,a_n)=(f_1(a_1m_1+\dots+a_nm_n),\dots,f_n(a_1m_1+\dots+a_nm_n)).$$

Comment: How can we see that $M$ is isomorphic to the image of $P?

Comment: @FofiKonstantopoulou Since $g\circ f=\text {id}_M$, $f$ is injective, so the image of $f\circ g $ is isomorphic to the image of $g $, and $g $ is surjective, so the image of $g $ is $M $.

Comment: great, thanks very much!